# Check for undefined failing in Angular 7

Tags: angular

I am trying to do an undefined check on number variable in Angular 7. Though the value is undefined it doesnt satisfy the condition. Could you tell me where I am going wrong.

```
public init(val: string, selectedClassficationId: number) {
        this.Mode = val;
        if (selectedClassficationId !== undefined) {
        this.getClassificationDetails(selectedClassficationId);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If `selectedClassficationId !== undefined` evals to `true` then `selectedClassficationId` can't be `undefined. You should probably use a truthy evaluation instead on that value. `if (selectedClassficationId) { }`

Comment: @Tom Added condition for `0` also!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try this?

The if block will not be executed if the value for `selectedClassficationId`  is  `undefined`, `null`, `false`, `0`.

```
if (selectedClassficationId || selectedClassficationId == 0) {
  this.getClassificationDetails(selectedClassficationId);
}
else {
  console.log('The value is either undefined, null, false, 0', selectedClassficationId);
}
```

[`Here`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-abjbaf) is the detailed example for each use case:

Comment: Also, `0`. Which might be a problem for numbers.

Comment: @mbojko yup added!

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this

```
public init(val: string, selectedClassficationId: number) {
        this.Mode = val;
        if (selectedClassficationId != null) { // != null is check null as well as undefine at the same time 
        this.getClassificationDetails(selectedClassficationId);
        }
    }
```

i hope it helps you out